# FreeMat has been installed but can not start, no icon seen

Tags: apt

After apt install the FreeMat package, no icon appeared. No way to start the software. My system is Ubuntu, the file is dot.rpm file.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How FreeMat was installed? Which installation source do you use?

Answer (score 1):

FreeMat is [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/freemat) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, it has necessary [desktop-file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=freemat.desktop) in the package.

To correctly install the application on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freemat
```

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (and really newer) there is a problem - this version does not ship Qt4 in the repositories. So we need to use special [third-party PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Erock-core/+archive/ubuntu/qt4) to get it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo apt-get update

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi6_3.2.1-8_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/freemat/freemat_4.2+dfsg1-6_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/freemat/freemat-data_4.2+dfsg1-6_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/freemat/freemat-help_4.2+dfsg1-6_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libffi6_3.2.1-8_amd64.deb ./freemat_4.2+dfsg1-6_amd64.deb ./freemat-data_4.2+dfsg1-6_all.deb ./freemat-help_4.2+dfsg1-6_all.deb
```

The above method may be adapted for Ubuntu 21.04 using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4
sudo sed -i "s/hirsute/focal/g" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rock-core-ubuntu-qt4-hirsute.list
sudo apt-get update

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi6_3.2.1-8_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/freemat/freemat_4.2+dfsg1-6_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/freemat/freemat-data_4.2+dfsg1-6_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/freemat/freemat-help_4.2+dfsg1-6_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libffi6_3.2.1-8_amd64.deb ./freemat_4.2+dfsg1-6_amd64.deb ./freemat-data_4.2+dfsg1-6_all.deb ./freemat-help_4.2+dfsg1-6_all.deb
```